# How to display In Struts2 server side validation error message in popup?

Tags: struts2

Please let me know how if server side validation error message should be display in popup window.
In Struts2, we display server side error message using `<s:actionerror/>`. Please help how to do?

Comment: You should revise your question to include a lot more detail about what you want to do, what you have tried so far, and what results you have had from what you have tried. This question is way too vague at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

shahith,
 
one ways is to create a hidden variable in your jsp for errors and mapped it either with bean or declare variable in action class with getter n setter , once you get an error set this error to this declared variable, when page loads, through java script read the value of this variable and if you find any value in this hidden variable then display it in alert.
hope this will help...